# Make JsonGetter case insensitive

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using **JacksonAnnotation** along with **Spring Framework** to parse a JSON that I get from a web service for my app.

I have the same data structure coming from two distinct methods but there is a field in one of them that comes capitalized. I don't want to create two data structures just because of that.

Is there any way that I make JsonGetter case insensitive or at least make it accept two version of a string?

Currently I have to use this for method A

```
@JsonGetter("CEP")
public String getCEP() {
    return this.cep;
}
```

and this for method B

```
@JsonGetter("Cep")
public String getCEP() {
    return this.cep;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new setter method for each possibility of property name:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"Cep\":\"value\"}", Entity.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"CEP\":\"value\"}", Entity.class));
    }
}

class Entity {

    private String cep;

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    @JsonSetter("Cep")
    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    @JsonSetter("CEP")
    public void setCepCapitalized(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity [cep=" + cep + "]";
    }
}
```